# Difference between prev and prevs?

Tags: alloy

What's the difference between these two:

```
t.prev
t.prevs
```

where `t: Time` and `Time` is ordered:

```
open util/ordering[Time]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t.prev` returns the direct predecessor of `t` in the ordering.

`t.prevs` returns the set of all elements preceding `t` in the ordering.

As an example consider the following ordering `T0 < T1 < T2 < T3`, Then:

```
T2.prev= T1

T2.prevs= {T0,T1}
```

Comment: Excellent! Great explanation. Thank you @Loïc Gammaitoni

Comment: My pleasure ;-)